# Using show/hide with 'slide' effect, how to start/stop sliding at an offset?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a menu that opens up on

```
$('.my_menu').show('slide', {direction:'up'}, 500, function() {}, function() {});
```

and closes on

```
$('.my_menu').hide('slide', {direction:'up'}, 200, function() {}, function() {});
```

Now, when it closes I don't want the menu to go all the way back to hidden, I would like to see parts of the menu as to give a visual hint that there's actually something there.

Is there an offset option to the show/hide command?

/T

Answer (score 2):

have you tried:

```
var height = $('.my_menu').outerHeight() - 4; // show 4 pixels
$('.my_menu').hide('slide', {direction:'up', distance: height}, 200, function() {}, function() {});
```

(take a look at [effects.slide.js](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide#options))